# Как сделать так чтобы одна таблица создавалась на основе двух предыдущих?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Привет!Я разрабатываю для себя приложение на С# с использованием Entity Framework и у меня начало получатся добавлять и выводить данные с базы но мне нужно сделать так чтобы в таблице RecipeIngredient сразу после добавления рецепта добавлялись ингредиенты к нему в виде Id этого ингредиента.
Вот так сейчас выглядит модель моей бд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Продукты которые нужны для рецепта я храню в List-масиве `List<string> productsAddList = new List<string>();`Мне кажется при добавлении можно будет его перебирать в цикле и сопоставлять данные в RecipeIngredient.RecipeIngredient я создал потому что мне нужно будет сделать потом поиск рецептов по продуктам.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class PlusRecepies : Form
    {
        int x = 0;
        List<string> productsAddList = new List<string>();

        public PlusRecepies()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlusToFlp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = ProductPlus.Text;

            productsAddList.Add(ProductPlus.Text);
            }



        private void AddRecepieToDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe
            {
                Instructions = RecepiePRText.Text,
                Name = NameRecipe.Text,
                Prop_Time = Convert.ToInt32(PropTime.Text)
            };


            for (int i = 0; i < productsAddList.Count; i++)
            {
                Ingredients ingredient = new Ingredients
                {
                    Name = productsAddList[i]
                };
                context.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
                recipe.RecipeIngredient.Add(ingredient);
            }


            context.Recipe.Add(recipe);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }




    }
}
```

Ingredients.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Ingredients
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Ingredients()
        {
            this.RecipeIngredient = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Recipe.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Recipe
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Recipe()
        {
            this.RecipeIngredient = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Prop_Time { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RecipeIngredients.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class RecipeIngredient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }

        public virtual Ingredients Ingredients { get; set; }
        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите вместо картинки код своих Entity-классов

Comment: Выложил все три класса.

Comment: Перед сохранением сделайте `recipe.RecipeIngredient.Add(ingredient)`. ЗЫ. лучше использовать подход CodeFirst и думать в его терминах, тогда таких вопросов у вас и возникать не будет, думаю

Comment: И так свяжется ингредиент и рецепт?

Comment: Да, в этом и есть одна из фишек EF :) Кстати о промежуточной таблице RecipeIngredient вам вообще знать не нужно (и тем более лезть в нее)

Comment: ingredient это обьект с параметром Name который должен быть записан в таблицу Ingredients.Получается EF сам соединит эти две таблицы?Но по какому правилу?Ведь у каждого Id рецепта должно быть несколько id ингредиентов.

Comment: Плюс я получаю ошибку когда добавляю эту строку recipe.RecipeIngredient.Add(ingredient);

Comment: EF сам создаст запись таблице RecipeIngredient с нужными значениями Id, вам достаточно написать так, как я показал вам

Comment: Что за ошибка? Если NRE, то сначала создайте коллекцию: `recipe.RecipeIngredient = new List<RecipeIngredient>()`

Comment: Обновил код и добавил скрин.Я добавил то чтобы в масиве продукты хранились.

`for (int i = 0; i < productsAddList.Count; i++)
            {
                Ingredients ingredient = new Ingredients
                {
                    Name = productsAddList[i]
                };
                context.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
                recipe.RecipeIngredient.Add(ingredient);
            }`

Comment: Ааа, блин. Это кривое решение. Я рекомендую вам использовать подход CodeFirst всё же. Иначе вам еще придется создавать вручную и экземпляры RecipeIngredient, что сопряжено с ошибками

Comment: Та я понимаю что наплодил кучу не лучшего кода но сделать это спряжение с таблицами это последнее что осталось чтобы работала программа + переписывать не хочется).

Comment: Ну тогда вместо того что я вам написал, создавайте экземпляр `RecipeIngredient recipeIngredient = new RecipeIngredient { Ingredients = ingredient, Recipe = recipe };` и добавляйте его `context.RecipeIngredient.Add(recipeIngredient);`

Comment: Добавление работает,ошибок нету,спасибо.

Comment: Но помните, что это плохой подход, почитайте про CodeFirst: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/